# Java - displaying values from array in different textfields

Tags: java, user-interface, textfield

I have a java GUI created using Jigloo tool in Eclipse, where I have several textfields, let's call them for example oneTF, twoTF, threeTF and fourTF.

In different class I have an array of integers. I have a getter method where I pass down an index and it returns me a value from the array.

I need to implement a method, which will display these values in my GUI, but I want to have one method, where I will pass the index and it will update just one particular textfield.

For example if I will pass down index 0, it will get a value from my array using my getter method and display it in oneTF. When I pass down index 1, it will display it in twoTF. When I pass down 2, it will update threeTF etc.

Is there any way how to do it?

Thanks you very much in advance.

Comment: Put your textfields to an array.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. But how can I do that? I mean, I know how to make an array, but how am I going to handle the different location and size parameters of those textfields?                        Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am beginner with Java.

Comment: @user3084515: don't ever set the size and location of a Swing component. Use layout managers to lay out your components. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Comment: @user3084515 You can still have your named references if you prefer, though it is not necessary.

Comment: I have one more problem with this. I have initialized a new array of textfields - JTextField[] allField = new JTextField [10]; and in constructor I have initialized textfields in this array - for(int a = 0;a < 10;a++){
allField[a] = new JTextField(String.valueOf(0));
allField[a].setBounds(189 + a * 50, 48, 39, 23);

} - but it for some reason does not display my textfields when I run the GUI. Why is that? How can I fix it?   I am really sorry for messy code display, I don't know how to display it properly in comments.

Comment: @user3084515 You have not added them to the parent component.